# Insert if not exist php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have the code

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO authors (author) VALUES ('$rec_fic_author') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM authors WHERE author='$rec_fic_author')") or die("cannot insert author");
```

Where authors is the table containing authorID (pk), and author
$rec_fic_author is a _POST variable

I'm trying to make it so that when a person is adding an author, the code checks the database for anyone with the same name (under the author column). If not, then add the entry
I have author as TEXT, and for some reason, I can't make it unique in phpMyAdmin.
I looked into REPLACE and INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, but as I understand they both need the value in question to be a unique/PK value. This is not the case here.

Help?

Comment: Could you share your table structure with information such as PK

Comment: Why dont you just do a SELECT for the author and check the mysql_num_rows()? If its equal 0 do the insert.

Comment: author as TEXT seems a bit over-dimensioned, a CHAR/VARCHAR should do; and these can have a UNIQUE INDEX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to operate with PK or with UK (as wonk0 suggested), then you could use INSERT statement with INGNORE clause.

[INSERT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good query and NOT EXISTS is typically quite fast if you have good indexes. But i am wondering why this is not working!

I think this can be useful for your concern... [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554509/sql-improve-not-exists-query-performance), Check it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is no valid syntax for an INSERT; cf http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html

Comment: @wonk0, i didn't mean that this is a valid, but i suggest a already posted link, and if it is possible that is good.... (please up-vote my answer).